# $result variable not recognized in MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

Amongst what I'm sure are a plethora of other problems, the $result variable isn't being recognized

getting a

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <?PHP

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'edumacation');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$result = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `student`
    WHERE `id` = 1
SQL;


while($row = 
        $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Grade</th><th>Favorite Teacher</th><th>Date Enrolled</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['grade'] . "</td><td>" . $row['fav_teacher'] . "</td></tr>" . $row['enrolled'] . "<br />";
    echo "</table>";
}

?>
   </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're not actually *executing* the query, just setting a string to what you want the SQL to be. Something like this would work better;

```
$sql = <<<SQL
  SELECT *
  FROM `student`
  WHERE `id` = 1
SQL;

if ($result = $db->query($sql)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually running a query against your DB with the connection you setup.  `$result` in your example you is just a HEREDOC string.

You need to do something like:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `id` = 1; ");
```

Then you can call the `fetch_assoc()` method on the $result object.